# Handling signal with exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to find a way to calculate the falling time of a signal, which looks like this [signal pulse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVvwc.png). The falling time is found by finding the value at which the signal falls below a certain level below the plateau. Here's what I tried so far, but I am not getting anywhere.

```
minvalue = np.argmin(data)                                              
for i in range(minvalue - 500, minvalue + 1, - 1):                      
    try:                                                                
        if data[i - 1] >= level and data[i] < level:                    
            return times[i]                                             
    except:                                                                                                                    
        continue
```

Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks.
Here's how I am using the defined function:

```
        t0 = self.crossingTime1(upADC, channel_data, times)
        t1 = self.crossingTime1(downADC, channel_data, times)
        fall_time = t1 - t0
```

So if either `t1` or `t0` aren't returned by the function, then it won't be possible to obtain a number, given that I will be trying to subtract a `None` object from a `float` object.

Comment: How can step be -1 if you want to go from, say, -500 to 1 (taking minvalue to be 0)? Also, how can program reach `continue` if preceding statement is a `return` statement (in `except` part of the code)? The variable `times` is also not clear from code. Moreover, if you have data, why do you need try and except?

Comment: My intention was to create a loop that iterated backwards, starting at minvalue and go backwards. The purpose is to find the time at which the signal exceeded the level. I attempted to use try and except to skip any iteration that doesn't satisfy the if-statement.

Comment: _Always_ add the version-agnostic [python] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It should work according to the description in your question.

```
minvalue = np.argmin(data)                                              
for i in range(minvalue + 1, minvalue - 500, -1):                      
    if data[i - 1] >= level and data[i] < level:                    
        return times[i]
```